# angular 4 accessing nested reactive form element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im having a reactive form like this which dynamically add when a button is clicked.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        freeItems: this._fb.array([
            this.initDetails(),
        ])
    });
}

initDetails() {
    return this._fb.group({
        offerProductId: ['', Validators.required],
        offerUnitId: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

I tried to access 'freeItems' like `console.log(this.myForm.get('freeItems').value);`
i get result as:

```
{  
   offerProductId:"5a579833029b7307a2604428",
   offerUnitId:"1243"
}{  
   offerProductId:"5a579833029b7307a2604428",
   offerUnitId:"2332"
}{  
   offerProductId:"5a579793029b7307a2604421",
   offerUnitId:"2323"
}
```

which is fine but i am unable to access the internal element of the 'freeItems' like disable(),value,setValue() the offerProductId or offerUnitId.

I tried this `console.log(this.myForm.get('freeItems.offerProductId'));` and get result as Null.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have an array. You need to tell Angular which index you're trying to access.

```
this.myForm.get('freeItems.0.offerProductId')
```

Comment: thanks alot. that works. i was confused how to add the array value. i didint realize we have to add like this.